# fine tune rspec before

Tags: ruby, rspec

In Rspec, we can setup some global before/after behavior like this:

```
config.before(:each) {blah...}
```

I can say:

```
config.before(:each, :type => :model) {blah...}
```

To have this block run only with model tests
But this wouldn't work:

```
config.before(:each, :type => [:model, :controller]) {blah...}
```

I have to repeat the same thing twice, one for model and one for controller. Is there any other way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at RSpec filters: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks/filters

They just match any arbitrary metadata, and rspec-rails adds the metadata :type => :model (or whatever) to each set of tests.

So, this config

```
config.before(:each, :type => [:model, :controller]) {blah...}
```

would only match tests with this metadata (matching the same value):

```
describe "matching tests", :type => [:model, :controller] {blah...}
```

Which basically means **the answer to your question is NO**.

Anyway, you could easily DIY it with something like this:

```
before_controller_and_model = lambda do
  do_stuff
end

config.before(:each, :type => :model)      { before_controller_and_model.call }
config.before(:each, :type => :controller) { before_controller_and_model.call }
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted. C'mon, if you're going to bother someone to help you, you should follow through with giving credit for correct answers.